# What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?

Tags: c#, json.net

At present, the structure of my code uses `XmlDocument` to load Xml data and then `SelectNodes` to iterate through a list of repeating items.

For each element, I am using `XmlNode.SelectSingleNode` to pick out the field elements.

I now want to use JSON.NET to achieve the same results with documents delivered to me as JSON. The answer can be something other than JSON.net, so long as it's C# integrable.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) has SelectToken. It uses a syntax similar to DataBinder.Eval to get JSON via a string expression:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse("{'People':[{'Name':'Jeff'},{'Name':'Joe'}]}");

// get name token of first person and convert to a string
string name = (string)o.SelectToken("People[0].Name");
```

Or if you wanted to select multiple values:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse("{'People':[{'Name':'Jeff','Roles':['Manager', 'Admin']}]}");

// get role array token of first person and convert to a list of strings
IList<string> names = (string)o.SelectToken("People[0].Roles").Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
```

Documentation: [**Querying JSON with SelectToken**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm)

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to do this in a case-insensitive way? Like `JToken.GetValue("something", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`?

Comment: Does using JObject loads the whole file/json into memory? If that is the case, what would be your approach when dealing with very long / big json inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an object hierarchy that you can map the the JSON? You could create an object tree (i.e. deserialize the JSON), and use LINQ's `Where`, `SelectMany`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marc. Specifically, Im using the twitter.com/status/mentions.json feed. I want to pass each "status" to an HTML Render without knowing (at buildtime) which fields it is using and allow it to pull fields with Json version of SelectSingleNode. A LINQ example would help alot :)

Comment: Ah, right. It wouldn't allow you to use an arbitrary string, if that is what you mean. It would need coding per scenario.