# Look Up any node in Json.NET

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I am using NewtonSoft Json.NET library for parsing JSON files in a .NET app. 
What I need to do is to pass the name of a node, and get the node if it exists, regardless of their level which is unknown beforehand.

For instance in a file:

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""ATest"": {
    ""MyTest"":
    [
       ""blah"",
       ""blah""
    ]
  }
}";
```

Is there a way to just use the value `"MyTest"` to fetch that node without having to know the parent's name like `jObject["ATest"]["MyTest"][0]`?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Is `Sizes` an array or an object? And you are missing a `"` in `Name`.

Comment: yes it was invalid, sorry. I just corrected it. That was just an example, the actual JSON doesn't matter. I was just looking for a way to find a node at any level given its name

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AFAIK there's no XPath-like query syntax for `JToken` / `JObject`, but you can make one fairly easily - see code below.

```
public static class StackOverflow_13033174
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string json = @"{ 
                          ""Name"": ""Apple"", 
                          ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000), 
                          ""Price"": 3.99, 
                          ""ATest"": { 
                            ""MyTest"": 
                            [ 
                               ""blah"", 
                               ""blah"" 
                            ] 
                          } 
                        }";

        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken myTest = jo.Descendants()
            .Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)t).Name == "MyTest")
            .Select(p => ((JProperty)p).Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(myTest);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `JObject.Parse` you can use the built-in [`JContainer.Descendants`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm) method.

Comment: For all readers who have the same question in my like I did: yes. `.Descandants()` returns *all* children recursively.

Comment: *AFAIK there's no XPath-like query syntax for `JToken` / `JObject`* - Json.NET does in fact support [tag:jsonpath] queries.  See [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1698175/3744182) and [How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36324494/3744182).  `JObject.Descendants()` will, of course, also work.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach using [JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EIKjnH

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

                
public static class StackOverflow_13033174
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string json = @"{ 
                      ""Name"": ""Apple"", 
                      ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000), 
                      ""Price"": 3.99, 
                      ""ATest"": { 
                        ""MyTest"": 
                        [ 
                           ""blah"", 
                           ""blah"" 
                        ] 
                      } 
                    }";

    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    
    JToken myTest = jo.SelectToken("*.MyTest");
    Console.WriteLine(myTest);
    }
}
```