# How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can I get the "myThings" array out of JSON that looks like the following using JSON.NET?

Example 1:

```
{
    "z": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    },
    "something": {
        "y": [1, 2],
        "somethingElse": {
            "1234": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "myThings": [{
                    "name": "bob",
                    "age": 3
                }, {
                    "name": "bob",
                    "age": 3
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
    "z": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    },
    "something": {
        "y": [1, 2],
        "somethingElse": {
            "7890": {
                "foo": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A couple things that I'm having difficulties with:

- One of the property names is a number that is unpredictable ("1234" and "7890")
- Sometimes the "myThings" array doesn't exist - in this case null or an empty array/collection is what I want to have

Another consideration in case it helps you: I do have a static class that represents the things inside of the myThings array, so my ideal return value would be `IEnumerable<MyThing>`

My first attempt was to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)` but I don't know how to handle the issues I mentioned above. In the end, I don't need the entire JSON string's worth of data, just that inside array named "myThings".

Comment: What do you mean by "unpredictable"? Does `somethingElse` only ever contain a single property with some numeric key?

Comment: By "unpredictable", I mean the number that is the object's name is always a different number. In my examples, I'm referring to the numbers "1234" and "7890".

Comment: Right, I understand that it can change, but what else do you know about the data structure? Can you always do something like `something.somethingElse` and then that will be the only key inside it?

Comment: The only change in structure is that number changing and the `myThings` object sometimes not existing. The rest of the structure is predictable. So yes, `something.somethingElse` is always there with a single number-named item in it. Just that number-named item may or may not contain an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) for this purpose.  It allows for querying JSON using wildcards and recursive searches using the [JSONPath syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

```
var root = JToken.Parse(json);
var myThings = root.SelectTokens("..myThings[*]").ToList();
```

Here `".."` is the *recursive descent* operator and `"myThings[*]"` means to return all array items of the property `"myThings"`.

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GR9yri).

If the array entries of `"myThings[*]"` correspond to some POCO `MyThing`, you can use [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize them after querying:

```
    var myThings = root.SelectTokens("..myThings[*]").Select(t => t.ToObject<MyThing>()).ToList();
```

Comment: This did it! Only thing I had to tweak was at the end I had `root.SelectTokens("..myThings[*]").Select(x => new {name= x["name"].ToString(), age=(int)x["age"]});`. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I like your addition better than my tweak. `ToObject` works much better. Thank you.