# Find pattern in json with json.net and linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I'm searching a json file, with the following structure:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {    
        "name": "obj1",
            "state": {
                "type": 4,
                    "childs": [
                         "state": {
                              "type": 5,
                               ...
```

The state can contain state as a child until any number of Levels. Now im trying to find all objects containing a certain Patterns of states, e.g. state 4 with child state 5 with child state 2.

My code so far is this.

```
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"j.json"));

        var oObjects=
            from p in o["objects"]
            where (string)p["state"] == "4"
            select (string)p["name"];
```

How can I expand the code to find all objects containing the search pattern on any Level?

Comment: Look into recursion.

Comment: You could try [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with the `..` recursive descent operator.  See [How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36324494/3744182).  There's also [`o.DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work for indefinite level, then you will need to use a recursive method like the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = @"{
        ""objects"": [
            {
                ""name"": ""obj1"",
                ""state"": {
                    ""type"": 4,
                    ""childs"": [
                        {
                            ""state"": {
                                ""type"": 5
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }";

    var obj = JObject.Parse(str);

    GetValidObjects(obj, new string[] { "4", "5" }); // Name list of valid objects
}
```

And the helper methods defined like:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetValidObjects(JObject obj, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    return obj["objects"]
        .Where(i => (string)i["state"]["type"] == values.First() && ContainsState((JArray)i["state"]["childs"], values.Skip(1)))
        .Select(i => (string)i["name"]);
}

public bool ContainsState(JArray childs, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    if (childs == null)
    {
        return values.Count() == 0;
    }

    return childs.Any(i => (string)i["state"]["type"] == values.First() && ContainsState((JArray)i["state"]["childs"], values.Skip(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to convert the json to xml and then use an xpath query to obtain the list of nodes.

```
        string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"j.json");
        XmlDocument document = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
        XmlNodeList nodes = document.SelectNodes("//name[../state[type[.=4] and childs/state[type[.=5] and childs/state[type[.=2]]]]]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SelectTokens](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) for this:

```
var objects = o.SelectTokens("$.objects[?(@.state.type == 4 
                       && @.state.childs[*].state.type == 5)].name")
                    .Select(s => (string)s)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Nice to know this helper method, but it will not work for different levels other than 2.