# Parsing a nested dictionary with arbitrary numerical keys and object array values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the json string

```
var testJson = @"{'entry1': {
                       '49208118': [
                          {
                             'description': 'just a description'
                          },
                          {
                             'description': 'another description' 
                          }
                       ],
                       '29439559': [
                          {
                             'description': 'just a description'
                          },
                          {
                             'description': 'another description' 
                          }
                       ]
                     }
                }";
```

The array value of the key `49208118` can be retrieved by

```
var root = JToken.Parse(testJson);
var descriptions = root.SelectTokens("..49208118[*]").ToList();
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324494/how-do-i-get-a-deeply-nested-property-from-json-string).

But how can the whole substructure under `entry1` be parsed into a dictionary

```
 Dictionary<string, JArray> descriptions;
```

mapping the numerical ids to arrays of `JObject`s?

Comment: But if the Key is unknown how do you know which element you want to access?

Comment: For the sake of this example, we can generalize to n numerical key-value pairs with arbitrary , dynamic numerical keys.

Comment: I think, I don't really understand your problem, but wouldn't something like `var root = d.SelectToken("$..entry1");` give you such a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since question is how you can parse `entry1` to `Dictionary<string, JArray>` - easiest option is:

```
JToken root = JToken.Parse(testJson);
Dictionary<string, JArray> descriptions = root["entry1"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, JArray>>();
```

Json.NET allows mixing of .NET classes (`Dictionary`) and his own classes (`JArray`) without problems when parsing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
string selector = String.Format("..{0}[*]", yourKey);
var descriptions = root.SelectTokens(selector).ToList();
```

Comment: What is "yourKey" ? Remember, the id is not known in advance.  The only thing known is that there is an arbitrary numerical key with an array value.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a flattened array or nested arrays?

Comment: The latter: Nested. I.e., a dictionarry { id : descriptions}