# Parsing Json string using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Json.NET in order to parse a json string but when i try to use SelectToken it returns null. Also it seems that Json.NET read the json string as 1 node

here is the JSON

```
[
   [{
      "input_index":0,
      "candidate_index":0,
      "delivery_line_1":"124 Main St",
      "last_line":"Cambridge MA 02138-5813",
      "delivery_point_barcode":"021385813991",
      "components":{
         "primary_number":"125",
         "street_name":"Main",
         "street_suffix":"St",
         "city_name":"Cambridge",
         "state_abbreviation":"MA",
         "zipcode":"02138",
         "plus4_code":"5813",
         "delivery_point":"99",
         "delivery_point_check_digit":"1"
      },
      "metadata":{
         "record_type":"H",
         "county_fips":"25017",
         "county_name":"New York",
         "carrier_route":"C025",
         "congressional_district":"08",
         "building_default_indicator":"Y"
      },
      "analysis":{
         "dpv_match_code":"D",
         "dpv_footnotes":"AAN1",
         "dpv_cmra":"N",
         "dpv_vacant":"N",
         "ews_match":false,
         "footnotes":"A#H#N#"
      }
   }]
]
```

and here is the code

```
JArray o = JArray.Parse(page);
string something = (string)o.SelectToken("county_name");
```

However it just returns me null and i am totally confused as there is something wrong with JSON.NET parsing this Json string

Comment: It's an array... an array doesn't have a `county_name`...

Comment: So how could i retrieve it...

Comment: Also they are double arrays. outer and inner one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698175/what-is-the-json-net-equivilant-of-xmls-xpath-selectnodes-selectsinglenode)

```
var data = GetJson();

//You can use the SelectToken to get the value similar to XPath.
var value = JArray.Parse(data)
                  .SelectToken("[0][0].metadata.county_name")
                  .Value<string>();
```

This can be extended to support multiple elements:

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(data);
var countyNames = new List<string>();

foreach(var element in jArray.SelectToken("[0]"))
{
    var value = element.SelectToken("metadata.county_name").Value<string>();

    countyNames.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: what is the use of `[0][0]`

Comment: First element of the unnamed outer array and first element of the unnamed inner array.

Comment: But i still get null using this code idk why!. i am sorry but could you have a little patience with me to solve this

Comment: Is you are getting `null` then either the JSON that you are receiving is different, it does not contain the same property, or there is a typo in your code.

Comment: Is that the complete JSON?

Comment: yea this is the complete on

Comment: Check that you are using the latest version of JSON.NET other than that I cannot think of anything.

Comment: i am using the latest version... well i will have to do some debugs however thank you very much for your very valuable help and i have marked your answer as the best

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that you basically have a wrapper around your actual object. You basically have:

```
Array of objects
  Object
    Metadata
    etc
```

So basically, get the first `JToken` out of the `JArray` and access the metadata from there.

Comment: Please make you answer richer with a code so another people after me could find it useful