# Tool to test Newtonsoft Json.NET Query

Tags: json.net

I'm hoping to find an online tool to design & test code to extract Json values using Newtonsoft Json.NET similar to the ones available for JavaScript e.g. http://www.jsonquerytool.com/.  I'm not looking for code, I'm hoping there is an online tool that generates code.

Comment: Are you looking for [`SelectToken()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)?  See [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1698175/3744182) and [Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645501/3744182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698175/what-is-the-json-net-equivalent-of-xmls-xpath-selectnodes-selectsinglenode)