# Is there a way to pull a json fragment from json string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I want to be able to pull section of json string in C#
e.g my json string looks like this

```
{
  "accountNumber": "",  
  "Business": "Dummy Business",
   ClientId": 123,
  "location": {
    "Location#": 1,
    "LocationID": "12345",
    "Address1": "21 Fuller Road",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "LOS ANGELES",
    "State": "CA",
    "Zipcode": "20012-1234",
    "County": "123"
   }
}
```

and I want to be able to extract data by json xpath such as location/Location# and it should return following result

```
"data": {
        "Location#": "1"
 }
```

Similarly when I use location xpath, it should return this result

```
"data": {
        "location": {
    "Location#": 1,
    "LocationID": "12345",
    "Address1": "21 Fuller Road",
    "Address2": "",
    "City": "LOS ANGELES",
    "State": "CA",
    "Zipcode": "20012-1234",
    "County": "123"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is the JSON.NET equivalent of XML's XPath, SelectNodes, SelectSingleNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1698175/3744182)

Answer (score 1):

As Icepickle said, you could use the [Newtonsoft.Json package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and the [JObject.SelectToken()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method to select a JToken using a JPath expression.

Please refer the following sample code:

```
        //required using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
        string jsonstr = @"{'accountNumber': '',
                        'Business': 'Dummy Business', 
                        'ClientId': 123, 
                        'location': {
                            'Location#': 1,
                            'LocationID': '12345',
                            'Address1': '21 Fuller Road',
                            'Address2': '','City': 'LOS ANGELES',
                            'State': 'CA',
                            'Zipcode': '20012-1234',
                            'County': '123'   
                            }
                        }";
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonstr);
        JToken acme = o.SelectToken("$.location");

        string result = @"{'data': { 'location':"+ acme.ToString() + "} }";
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, check [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)